# nx generate unable to create app/library from scratch

Tags: javascript, node.js

After some months of work, I faced that I cannot create an app or library anymore using the "nx g" command. I used nx version 13.x, but upgrading to 14.x didn't help.
F.e.

```
nx g lib data-access-whatever
ENOENT: No such file or directory, scandir ''C:\dev\someproject\packages\data-access-whatever''
```

So, I have two questions:

1. why it requires to have library directory (because I believe it should create it automatically)
2. why directory name is "packages", when it should be "libs"?

UPDATE #1: Q2 resolved by removing this line from `nx.json` file:

```
"extends": "@nrwl/workspace/presets/npm.json"
```